Is the Even–Paz cake-cutting protocol a finite algorithm that guarantees proportional and connected pieces?
In theorem 8.2 of "Cake-cutting algorithms" by Robertson and Webb, it is stated that
No finite algorithm can guarantee each of $n$ players at least $1/n$ of the cake using only $n - 1$ cuts when n $\geq$ 3.
The Even-Paz protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even–Paz_protocol) seems to violate this: it is finite and promises each of $n$ players a proportional and connected piece. Is the above theorem incorrect, or is my understanding of it incomplete?

The Even-Paz protocol makes $\Theta(n\log n)$ cuts in total, and only uses $n-1$ cuts in its final proportional, connected fair division. However these $n-1$ cuts used in the final fair division are not what Theorem 8.2 is referencing. Instead, Theorem 8.2 is talking about the total number of cuts. Thus the Even-Paz protocol does not violate Theorem 8.2.
